# Migrating to Bokeh >1.0: Missing 'arguments' parameter in server_session

Tags: python, django, bokeh

#### Background:

I have legacy production code which embeds Bokeh applications inside Django. The purpose is to serve user-specific dashboards. The Bokeh code accesses `username` arguments from the request, per the [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request).

The applications were built using `bokeh 0.13`.

On the Django side, the `username` argument is passed as in the example below:

#### Example snippet from `views.py`:

```
from bokeh.util import session_id
from bokeh.embed import server_session

def get_bokeh_script(user, url_suffix):
    bokeh_session_id = session_id.generate_session_id()
    bokeh_url = "https://" + settings.BOKEH_HOST + ":" + settings.BOKEH_PORT + url_suffix
    script = server_session(url=bokeh_url, session_id=bokeh_session_id, resources=None, arguments={"username":user.username})
    return script



def my_view1(request):
    url_suffix = "/my_suffix"
    script = get_bokeh_script(request.user, url_suffix)
    return render(request,'dashboard/index.html',{'script':script})
```

#### Current scenario:

I need to migrate the code to `bokeh >1.0`, particularly for the `on_session_destroyed` method of the `Document()` object.

However, it appears that the `arguments` parameter of `server_session` has been removed, per the [migration guide](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#migration-guide) (see also discussion [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8140)).

#### Question:

Is there a workaround that will enable me to pass `username` as an argument from Django to Bokeh, in version `1.0.*` ?

Comment: You are passing **user** because you serve Bokeh plots per user or because you want to check if user is logged in ? Or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

For Bokeh v1.0.4 you could try:

```
script = server_document(url = bokeh_url, 
                         relative_urls = False, 
                         resources = 'default', 
                         arguments={"bokeh-session-id": bokeh_session_id, 
                                    "username": user.username } )
```

It returns the script and allows `arguments` parameter.

Another option would be to pass the user using different methods e.g. `push_session()` which also allows arguments and constructs a `ClientSession`

If you are passing the user to check authentication then you could `pip install flask-user` and do:

```
@login_required
def my_view1(request):
    url_suffix = "/my_suffix"
    script = get_bokeh_script(request.user, url_suffix)
    return render(request,'dashboard/index.html',{'script':script})
```